# Controller factory receiving request for "favicon.ico"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, favicon, unhandled-exception

I've noticed that a request to `"favicon.ico"` is being passed to my ASP .NET MVC controller factory when using Google Chrome and the Visual Studio Development Server. The `controllerType` parameter has a value of `null` which is unsurprisingly resulting in an unhandled exception, which I only know about because of an error log.

Any ideas where the request is coming from and why ASP .NET is letting it get to the controller factory? CSS files and images for example are being correctly filtered out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With IIS7 in integrated mode all requests are tunneled to the pipe. you can add it to your ignore routes

[asp.net mvc does it handle all requests? - iis 7 integrated mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727908/asp-net-mvc-does-it-handle-all-requests-iis-7-integrated-mode)

Another resource

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/02/26/asp-net-mvc-ignore-requests-to-favicon-ico.aspx

Bear in mind to you only seeing this as you are in debug mode. Your users wont see it (Not optimal still, but hey I didn't design it)

Comment: Oh.... I take it back. Now I'm just getting a 'File Not Found' exception instead.

Comment: Yes, that will prevent it from being attempted map to a controller. You need to add the file too (easiest solution) - Added some more info

Comment: I've added the file. But now there's no need for any other changes. It seems as if the file is not found then it is sent to the controller factory. If MVC is told to ignore the route then some other layer says it can't find the file. Just add the file and there's no issue. I would have actually seen a symptom of this on the live server because my log file would be filled with the resulting exceptions!

Comment: Yes, however there might be a problem if you expand your routes and the request hap hazzardly gets qualified for the route. Best keep it in the ignore path in there

Comment: Ahhh... looks like someone using the exception logger I'm using has another solution... http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFilterExamples

Answer (score 2):

I have also noticed this occuring with chrome. I believe it is the browser looking for the site favicon (little icon next to its tab) with the default path of /favicon.ico. MVC trys to find a controller matching that route and comes up blank.

Easiest fix is probably just to add favicon image in your root directory called favicon.ico or using a link tag in the head section of your html to point it somewhere else.

eg

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```